# Pipenv fails when installing packages for python 3.6

Tags: python-3.x, development-environment, pipenv

I am working on a project that requires `pipenv`, and python 3.6. When I run `pipenv sync`, it I get the error messages

```
An error occurred while installing django-markdown-deux==1.0.5 --hash=sha256:5b4a3cd9454af5b4cec0e19151b41d98d09400ddae0688afb81dbf62a4edafff! Will try again.
An error occurred while installing easy-thumbnails==2.7 --hash=sha256:e4e7a0dd4001f56bfd4058428f2c91eafe27d33ef3b8b33ac4e013b159b9ff91! Will try again.
```

As well as a privately maintained library withheld for privacy reasons (I have tried to remove this, it does not help.) pipenv then tries to "Installing initially failed dependencies…", before spewing out a wall of errors of like

```
[InstallError]:       retcode = do_sync(
[InstallError]:   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/pipenv/core.py", line 2884, in do_sync
[InstallError]:       do_init(
[InstallError]:   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/pipenv/core.py", line 1305, in do_init
[InstallError]:       do_install_dependencies(
[InstallError]:   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/pipenv/core.py", line 899, in do_install_dependencies
[InstallError]:       batch_install(
[InstallError]:   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/pipenv/core.py", line 796, in batch_install
[InstallError]:       _cleanup_procs(procs, failed_deps_queue, retry=retry)
[InstallError]:   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/pipenv/core.py", line 703, in _cleanup_procs
[InstallError]:       raise exceptions.InstallError(c.dep.name, extra=err_lines)
[pipenv.exceptions.InstallError]: Looking in indexes: https://pypi.python.org/simple
[pipenv.exceptions.InstallError]: Collecting django-markdown-deux==1.0.5
[pipenv.exceptions.InstallError]:   Using cached django-markdown-deux-1.0.5.zip (16 kB)
[pipenv.exceptions.InstallError]: Building wheels for collected packages: django-markdown-deux
[pipenv.exceptions.InstallError]:   Building wheel for django-markdown-deux (setup.py): started
[pipenv.exceptions.InstallError]:   Building wheel for django-markdown-deux (setup.py): finished with status 'error'
[pipenv.exceptions.InstallError]:   ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
[pipenv.exceptions.InstallError]:    command: /home/martin/.local/share/virtualenvs/nablaweb-2TimVObB/bin/python -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'/tmp/pip-install-7100f1_i/django-markdown-deux/setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'/tmp/pip-install-7100f1_i/django-markdown-deux/setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' bdist_wheel -d /tmp/pip-wheel-b1rphrl8
[pipenv.exceptions.InstallError]:        cwd: /tmp/pip-install-7100f1_i/django-markdown-deux/
[pipenv.exceptions.InstallError]:   Complete output (64 lines):
[pipenv.exceptions.InstallError]:   running bdist_wheel
[pipenv.exceptions.InstallError]:   running build
[pipenv.exceptions.InstallError]:   running build_py
[pipenv.exceptions.InstallError]:   creating build
[pipenv.exceptions.InstallError]:   creating build/lib
[pipenv.exceptions.InstallError]:   creating build/lib/markdown_deux
[pipenv.exceptions.InstallError]:   copying lib/markdown_deux/__init__.py -> build/lib/markdown_deux
[pipenv.exceptions.InstallError]:   running egg_info
[pipenv.exceptions.InstallError]:   writing lib/django_markdown_deux.egg-info/PKG-INFO
[pipenv.exceptions.InstallError]:   writing dependency_links to lib/django_markdown_deux.egg-info/dependency_links.txt
[pipenv.exceptions.InstallError]:   writing requirements to lib/django_markdown_deux.egg-info/requires.txt
[pipenv.exceptions.InstallError]:   writing top-level names to lib/django_markdown_deux.egg-info/top_level.txt
[pipenv.exceptions.InstallError]:   reading manifest file 'lib/django_markdown_deux.egg-info/SOURCES.txt'
[pipenv.exceptions.InstallError]:   reading manifest template 'MANIFEST.in'
[pipenv.exceptions.InstallError]:   writing manifest file 'lib/django_markdown_deux.egg-info/SOURCES.txt'
[pipenv.exceptions.InstallError]:   creating build/lib/markdown_deux/conf
[pipenv.exceptions.InstallError]:   copying lib/markdown_deux/conf/__init__.py -> build/lib/markdown_deux/conf
[pipenv.exceptions.InstallError]:   copying lib/markdown_deux/conf/settings.py -> build/lib/markdown_deux/conf
[pipenv.exceptions.InstallError]:   creating build/lib/markdown_deux/templates
[pipenv.exceptions.InstallError]:   creating build/lib/markdown_deux/templates/markdown_deux
[pipenv.exceptions.InstallError]:   copying lib/markdown_deux/templates/markdown_deux/markdown_cheatsheet.html -> build/lib/markdown_deux/templates/markdown_deux
[pipenv.exceptions.InstallError]:   creating build/lib/markdown_deux/templatetags
[pipenv.exceptions.InstallError]:   copying lib/markdown_deux/templatetags/__init__.py -> build/lib/markdown_deux/templatetags
[pipenv.exceptions.InstallError]:   copying lib/markdown_deux/templatetags/markdown_deux_tags.py -> build/lib/markdown_deux/templatetags
[pipenv.exceptions.InstallError]:   warning: build_py: byte-compiling is disabled, skipping.
[pipenv.exceptions.InstallError]:   
[pipenv.exceptions.InstallError]:   installing to build/bdist.linux-x86_64/wheel
[pipenv.exceptions.InstallError]:   running install
[pipenv.exceptions.InstallError]:   running install_lib
[pipenv.exceptions.InstallError]:   Traceback (most recent call last):
[pipenv.exceptions.InstallError]:     File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
[pipenv.exceptions.InstallError]:     File "/tmp/pip-install-7100f1_i/django-markdown-deux/setup.py", line 42, in <module>
[pipenv.exceptions.InstallError]:       zip_safe=False,
[pipenv.exceptions.InstallError]:     File "/home/martin/.local/share/virtualenvs/nablaweb-2TimVObB/lib/python3.6/site-packages/setuptools/__init__.py", line 145, in setup
[pipenv.exceptions.InstallError]:       return distutils.core.setup(**attrs)
[pipenv.exceptions.InstallError]:     File "/home/martin/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/distutils/core.py", line 148, in setup
[pipenv.exceptions.InstallError]:       dist.run_commands()
[pipenv.exceptions.InstallError]:     File "/home/martin/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/distutils/dist.py", line 955, in run_commands
[pipenv.exceptions.InstallError]:       self.run_command(cmd)
[pipenv.exceptions.InstallError]:     File "/home/martin/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/distutils/dist.py", line 974, in run_command
[pipenv.exceptions.InstallError]:       cmd_obj.run()
[pipenv.exceptions.InstallError]:     File "/home/martin/.local/share/virtualenvs/nablaweb-2TimVObB/lib/python3.6/site-packages/wheel/bdist_wheel.py", line 259, in run
[pipenv.exceptions.InstallError]:       self.run_command('install')
[pipenv.exceptions.InstallError]:     File "/home/martin/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/distutils/cmd.py", line 313, in run_command
[pipenv.exceptions.InstallError]:       self.distribution.run_command(command)
[pipenv.exceptions.InstallError]:     File "/home/martin/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/distutils/dist.py", line 974, in run_command
[pipenv.exceptions.InstallError]:       cmd_obj.run()
[pipenv.exceptions.InstallError]:     File "/home/martin/.local/share/virtualenvs/nablaweb-2TimVObB/lib/python3.6/site-packages/setuptools/command/install.py", line 61, in run
[pipenv.exceptions.InstallError]:       return orig.install.run(self)
[pipenv.exceptions.InstallError]:     File "/home/martin/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/distutils/command/install.py", line 557, in run
[pipenv.exceptions.InstallError]:       self.run_command(cmd_name)
[pipenv.exceptions.InstallError]:     File "/home/martin/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/distutils/cmd.py", line 313, in run_command
[pipenv.exceptions.InstallError]:       self.distribution.run_command(command)
[pipenv.exceptions.InstallError]:     File "/home/martin/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/distutils/dist.py", line 973, in run_command
[pipenv.exceptions.InstallError]:       cmd_obj.ensure_finalized()
[pipenv.exceptions.InstallError]:     File "/home/martin/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/distutils/cmd.py", line 107, in ensure_finalized
[pipenv.exceptions.InstallError]:       self.finalize_options()
[pipenv.exceptions.InstallError]:     File "/home/martin/.local/share/virtualenvs/nablaweb-2TimVObB/lib/python3.6/site-packages/setuptools/command/install_lib.py", line 17, in finalize_options
[pipenv.exceptions.InstallError]:       self.set_undefined_options('install',('install_layout','install_layout'))
[pipenv.exceptions.InstallError]:     File "/home/martin/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/distutils/cmd.py", line 290, in set_undefined_options
[pipenv.exceptions.InstallError]:       setattr(self, dst_option, getattr(src_cmd_obj, src_option))
[pipenv.exceptions.InstallError]:     File "/home/martin/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/distutils/cmd.py", line 103, in __getattr__
[pipenv.exceptions.InstallError]:       raise AttributeError(attr)
[pipenv.exceptions.InstallError]:   AttributeError: install_layout
[pipenv.exceptions.InstallError]:   ----------------------------------------
[pipenv.exceptions.InstallError]:   ERROR: Failed building wheel for django-markdown-deux
[pipenv.exceptions.InstallError]:   Running setup.py clean for django-markdown-deux
[pipenv.exceptions.InstallError]: Failed to build django-markdown-deux
[pipenv.exceptions.InstallError]: Installing collected packages: django-markdown-deux
[pipenv.exceptions.InstallError]:     Running setup.py install for django-markdown-deux: started
[pipenv.exceptions.InstallError]:     Running setup.py install for django-markdown-deux: finished with status 'error'
[pipenv.exceptions.InstallError]:     ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
[pipenv.exceptions.InstallError]:      command: /home/martin/.local/share/virtualenvs/nablaweb-2TimVObB/bin/python -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'/tmp/pip-install-7100f1_i/django-markdown-deux/setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'/tmp/pip-install-7100f1_i/django-markdown-deux/setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record /tmp/pip-record-_v1a0e1f/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers /home/martin/.local/share/virtualenvs/nablaweb-2TimVObB/include/site/python3.6/django-markdown-deux
[pipenv.exceptions.InstallError]:          cwd: /tmp/pip-install-7100f1_i/django-markdown-deux/
[pipenv.exceptions.InstallError]:     Complete output (56 lines):
[pipenv.exceptions.InstallError]:     running install
[pipenv.exceptions.InstallError]:     running build
[pipenv.exceptions.InstallError]:     running build_py
[pipenv.exceptions.InstallError]:     creating build
[pipenv.exceptions.InstallError]:     creating build/lib
[pipenv.exceptions.InstallError]:     creating build/lib/markdown_deux
[pipenv.exceptions.InstallError]:     copying lib/markdown_deux/__init__.py -> build/lib/markdown_deux
[pipenv.exceptions.InstallError]:     running egg_info
[pipenv.exceptions.InstallError]:     writing lib/django_markdown_deux.egg-info/PKG-INFO
[pipenv.exceptions.InstallError]:     writing dependency_links to lib/django_markdown_deux.egg-info/dependency_links.txt
[pipenv.exceptions.InstallError]:     writing requirements to lib/django_markdown_deux.egg-info/requires.txt
[pipenv.exceptions.InstallError]:     writing top-level names to lib/django_markdown_deux.egg-info/top_level.txt
[pipenv.exceptions.InstallError]:     reading manifest file 'lib/django_markdown_deux.egg-info/SOURCES.txt'
[pipenv.exceptions.InstallError]:     reading manifest template 'MANIFEST.in'
[pipenv.exceptions.InstallError]:     writing manifest file 'lib/django_markdown_deux.egg-info/SOURCES.txt'
[pipenv.exceptions.InstallError]:     creating build/lib/markdown_deux/conf
[pipenv.exceptions.InstallError]:     copying lib/markdown_deux/conf/__init__.py -> build/lib/markdown_deux/conf
[pipenv.exceptions.InstallError]:     copying lib/markdown_deux/conf/settings.py -> build/lib/markdown_deux/conf
[pipenv.exceptions.InstallError]:     creating build/lib/markdown_deux/templates
[pipenv.exceptions.InstallError]:     creating build/lib/markdown_deux/templates/markdown_deux
[pipenv.exceptions.InstallError]:     copying lib/markdown_deux/templates/markdown_deux/markdown_cheatsheet.html -> build/lib/markdown_deux/templates/markdown_deux
[pipenv.exceptions.InstallError]:     creating build/lib/markdown_deux/templatetags
[pipenv.exceptions.InstallError]:     copying lib/markdown_deux/templatetags/__init__.py -> build/lib/markdown_deux/templatetags
[pipenv.exceptions.InstallError]:     copying lib/markdown_deux/templatetags/markdown_deux_tags.py -> build/lib/markdown_deux/templatetags
[pipenv.exceptions.InstallError]:     warning: build_py: byte-compiling is disabled, skipping.
[pipenv.exceptions.InstallError]:     
[pipenv.exceptions.InstallError]:     running install_lib
[pipenv.exceptions.InstallError]:     Traceback (most recent call last):
[pipenv.exceptions.InstallError]:       File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
[pipenv.exceptions.InstallError]:       File "/tmp/pip-install-7100f1_i/django-markdown-deux/setup.py", line 42, in <module>
[pipenv.exceptions.InstallError]:         zip_safe=False,
[pipenv.exceptions.InstallError]:       File "/home/martin/.local/share/virtualenvs/nablaweb-2TimVObB/lib/python3.6/site-packages/setuptools/__init__.py", line 145, in setup
[pipenv.exceptions.InstallError]:         return distutils.core.setup(**attrs)
[pipenv.exceptions.InstallError]:       File "/home/martin/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/distutils/core.py", line 148, in setup
[pipenv.exceptions.InstallError]:         dist.run_commands()
[pipenv.exceptions.InstallError]:       File "/home/martin/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/distutils/dist.py", line 955, in run_commands
[pipenv.exceptions.InstallError]:         self.run_command(cmd)
[pipenv.exceptions.InstallError]:       File "/home/martin/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/distutils/dist.py", line 974, in run_command
[pipenv.exceptions.InstallError]:         cmd_obj.run()
[pipenv.exceptions.InstallError]:       File "/home/martin/.local/share/virtualenvs/nablaweb-2TimVObB/lib/python3.6/site-packages/setuptools/command/install.py", line 61, in run
[pipenv.exceptions.InstallError]:         return orig.install.run(self)
[pipenv.exceptions.InstallError]:       File "/home/martin/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/distutils/command/install.py", line 557, in run
[pipenv.exceptions.InstallError]:         self.run_command(cmd_name)
[pipenv.exceptions.InstallError]:       File "/home/martin/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/distutils/cmd.py", line 313, in run_command
[pipenv.exceptions.InstallError]:         self.distribution.run_command(command)
[pipenv.exceptions.InstallError]:       File "/home/martin/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/distutils/dist.py", line 973, in run_command
[pipenv.exceptions.InstallError]:         cmd_obj.ensure_finalized()
[pipenv.exceptions.InstallError]:       File "/home/martin/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/distutils/cmd.py", line 107, in ensure_finalized
[pipenv.exceptions.InstallError]:         self.finalize_options()
[pipenv.exceptions.InstallError]:       File "/home/martin/.local/share/virtualenvs/nablaweb-2TimVObB/lib/python3.6/site-packages/setuptools/command/install_lib.py", line 17, in finalize_options
[pipenv.exceptions.InstallError]:         self.set_undefined_options('install',('install_layout','install_layout'))
[pipenv.exceptions.InstallError]:       File "/home/martin/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/distutils/cmd.py", line 290, in set_undefined_options
[pipenv.exceptions.InstallError]:         setattr(self, dst_option, getattr(src_cmd_obj, src_option))
[pipenv.exceptions.InstallError]:       File "/home/martin/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/distutils/cmd.py", line 103, in __getattr__
[pipenv.exceptions.InstallError]:         raise AttributeError(attr)
[pipenv.exceptions.InstallError]:     AttributeError: install_layout
[pipenv.exceptions.InstallError]:     ----------------------------------------
[pipenv.exceptions.InstallError]: ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: /home/martin/.local/share/virtualenvs/nablaweb-2TimVObB/bin/python -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'/tmp/pip-install-7100f1_i/django-markdown-deux/setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'/tmp/pip-install-7100f1_i/django-markdown-deux/setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record /tmp/pip-record-_v1a0e1f/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers /home/martin/.local/share/virtualenvs/nablaweb-2TimVObB/include/site/python3.6/django-markdown-deux Check the logs for full command output.
```

This error message, formatted slightly differently comes also when trying to install `easy-thumbnails` via pipenv.

```
Error text: Looking in indexes: https://pypi.python.org/simple
Collecting easy-thumbnails
  Using cached easy-thumbnails-2.7.tar.gz (66 kB)
Requirement already satisfied, skipping upgrade: django<4.0,>=1.11 in /home/martin/.local/share/virtualenvs/nablaweb-2TimVObB/lib/python3.6/site-packages (from easy-thumbnails->-r /tmp/pipenv-9cou5x98-requirements/pipenv-phwkyn6c-requirement.txt (line 1)) (3.0.7)
Requirement already satisfied, skipping upgrade: pillow in /home/martin/.local/share/virtualenvs/nablaweb-2TimVObB/lib/python3.6/site-packages (from easy-thumbnails->-r /tmp/pipenv-9cou5x98-requirements/pipenv-phwkyn6c-requirement.txt (line 1)) (7.2.0)
Requirement already satisfied, skipping upgrade: asgiref~=3.2 in /home/martin/.local/share/virtualenvs/nablaweb-2TimVObB/lib/python3.6/site-packages (from django<4.0,>=1.11->easy-thumbnails->-r /tmp/pipenv-9cou5x98-requirements/pipenv-phwkyn6c-requirement.txt (line 1)) (3.2.10)
Requirement already satisfied, skipping upgrade: sqlparse>=0.2.2 in /home/martin/.local/share/virtualenvs/nablaweb-2TimVObB/lib/python3.6/site-packages (from django<4.0,>=1.11->easy-thumbnails->-r /tmp/pipenv-9cou5x98-requirements/pipenv-phwkyn6c-requirement.txt (line 1)) (0.3.1)
Requirement already satisfied, skipping upgrade: pytz in /home/martin/.local/share/virtualenvs/nablaweb-2TimVObB/lib/python3.6/site-packages (from django<4.0,>=1.11->easy-thumbnails->-r /tmp/pipenv-9cou5x98-requirements/pipenv-phwkyn6c-requirement.txt (line 1)) (2020.1)
Building wheels for collected packages: easy-thumbnails
  Building wheel for easy-thumbnails (setup.py): started
  Building wheel for easy-thumbnails (setup.py): finished with status 'error'
  Running setup.py clean for easy-thumbnails
Failed to build easy-thumbnails
Installing collected packages: easy-thumbnails
    Running setup.py install for easy-thumbnails: started
    Running setup.py install for easy-thumbnails: finished with status 'error'

  ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
   command: /home/martin/.local/share/virtualenvs/nablaweb-2TimVObB/bin/python -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'/tmp/pip-install-042_z1b9/easy-thumbnails/setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'/tmp/pip-install-042_z1b9/easy-thumbnails/setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' bdist_wheel -d /tmp/pip-wheel-bx7dcid2
       cwd: /tmp/pip-install-042_z1b9/easy-thumbnails/
  Complete output (110 lines):
  running bdist_wheel
  running build
  running build_py
  creating build
  creating build/lib
  creating build/lib/easy_thumbnails
  copying easy_thumbnails/namers.py -> build/lib/easy_thumbnails
  copying easy_thumbnails/get_version.py -> build/lib/easy_thumbnails
  copying easy_thumbnails/signal_handlers.py -> build/lib/easy_thumbnails
  copying easy_thumbnails/exceptions.py -> build/lib/easy_thumbnails
  copying easy_thumbnails/alias.py -> build/lib/easy_thumbnails
  copying easy_thumbnails/fields.py -> build/lib/easy_thumbnails
  copying easy_thumbnails/__init__.py -> build/lib/easy_thumbnails
  copying easy_thumbnails/models.py -> build/lib/easy_thumbnails
  copying easy_thumbnails/utils.py -> build/lib/easy_thumbnails
  copying easy_thumbnails/storage.py -> build/lib/easy_thumbnails
  copying easy_thumbnails/widgets.py -> build/lib/easy_thumbnails
  copying easy_thumbnails/source_generators.py -> build/lib/easy_thumbnails
  copying easy_thumbnails/signals.py -> build/lib/easy_thumbnails
  copying easy_thumbnails/processors.py -> build/lib/easy_thumbnails

... Character limit reached ....

    copying easy_thumbnails/templatetags/__init__.py -> build/lib/easy_thumbnails/templatetags
    copying easy_thumbnails/templatetags/thumbnail.py -> build/lib/easy_thumbnails/templatetags
    creating build/lib/easy_thumbnails/optimize
    copying easy_thumbnails/optimize/post_processor.py -> build/lib/easy_thumbnails/optimize
    copying easy_thumbnails/optimize/__init__.py -> build/lib/easy_thumbnails/optimize
    copying easy_thumbnails/optimize/conf.py -> build/lib/easy_thumbnails/optimize
    creating build/lib/easy_thumbnails/tests
    copying easy_thumbnails/tests/test_widgets.py -> build/lib/easy_thumbnails/tests
    copying easy_thumbnails/tests/test_files.py -> build/lib/easy_thumbnails/tests
    copying easy_thumbnails/tests/test_templatetags.py -> build/lib/easy_thumbnails/tests
    copying easy_thumbnails/tests/test_aliases.py -> build/lib/easy_thumbnails/tests
    copying easy_thumbnails/tests/mockoptim_fail.py -> build/lib/easy_thumbnails/tests
    copying easy_thumbnails/tests/test_management.py -> build/lib/easy_thumbnails/tests
    copying easy_thumbnails/tests/mockoptim.py -> build/lib/easy_thumbnails/tests
    copying easy_thumbnails/tests/__init__.py -> build/lib/easy_thumbnails/tests
    copying easy_thumbnails/tests/models.py -> build/lib/easy_thumbnails/tests
    copying easy_thumbnails/tests/test_source_generators.py -> build/lib/easy_thumbnails/tests
    copying easy_thumbnails/tests/test_engine.py -> build/lib/easy_thumbnails/tests
    copying easy_thumbnails/tests/test_models.py -> build/lib/easy_thumbnails/tests
    copying easy_thumbnails/tests/utils.py -> build/lib/easy_thumbnails/tests
    copying easy_thumbnails/tests/settings.py -> build/lib/easy_thumbnails/tests
    copying easy_thumbnails/tests/test_fields.py -> build/lib/easy_thumbnails/tests
    copying easy_thumbnails/tests/test_processors.py -> build/lib/easy_thumbnails/tests
    copying easy_thumbnails/tests/test_namers.py -> build/lib/easy_thumbnails/tests
    copying easy_thumbnails/tests/apps.py -> build/lib/easy_thumbnails/tests
    creating build/lib/easy_thumbnails/management
    copying easy_thumbnails/management/__init__.py -> build/lib/easy_thumbnails/management
    creating build/lib/easy_thumbnails/migrations
    copying easy_thumbnails/migrations/__init__.py -> build/lib/easy_thumbnails/migrations
    copying easy_thumbnails/migrations/0001_initial.py -> build/lib/easy_thumbnails/migrations
    copying easy_thumbnails/migrations/0002_thumbnaildimensions.py -> build/lib/easy_thumbnails/migrations
    creating build/lib/easy_thumbnails/management/commands
    copying easy_thumbnails/management/commands/thumbnail_cleanup.py -> build/lib/easy_thumbnails/management/commands
    copying easy_thumbnails/management/commands/__init__.py -> build/lib/easy_thumbnails/management/commands
    running egg_info
    writing easy_thumbnails.egg-info/PKG-INFO
    writing dependency_links to easy_thumbnails.egg-info/dependency_links.txt
    writing requirements to easy_thumbnails.egg-info/requires.txt
    writing top-level names to easy_thumbnails.egg-info/top_level.txt
    reading manifest file 'easy_thumbnails.egg-info/SOURCES.txt'
    reading manifest template 'MANIFEST.in'
    warning: no files found matching 'AUTHORS'
    no previously-included directories found matching 'docs/_build'
    writing manifest file 'easy_thumbnails.egg-info/SOURCES.txt'
    warning: build_py: byte-compiling is disabled, skipping.
    
    running install_lib
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
      File "/tmp/pip-install-042_z1b9/easy-thumbnails/setup.py", line 76, in <module>
        zip_safe=False,
      File "/home/martin/.local/share/virtualenvs/nablaweb-2TimVObB/lib/python3.6/site-packages/setuptools/__init__.py", line 145, in setup
        return distutils.core.setup(**attrs)
      File "/home/martin/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/distutils/core.py", line 148, in setup
        dist.run_commands()
      File "/home/martin/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/distutils/dist.py", line 955, in run_commands
        self.run_command(cmd)
      File "/home/martin/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/distutils/dist.py", line 974, in run_command
        cmd_obj.run()
      File "/home/martin/.local/share/virtualenvs/nablaweb-2TimVObB/lib/python3.6/site-packages/setuptools/command/install.py", line 61, in run
        return orig.install.run(self)
      File "/home/martin/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/distutils/command/install.py", line 557, in run
        self.run_command(cmd_name)
      File "/home/martin/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/distutils/cmd.py", line 313, in run_command
        self.distribution.run_command(command)
      File "/home/martin/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/distutils/dist.py", line 973, in run_command
        cmd_obj.ensure_finalized()
      File "/home/martin/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/distutils/cmd.py", line 107, in ensure_finalized
        self.finalize_options()
      File "/home/martin/.local/share/virtualenvs/nablaweb-2TimVObB/lib/python3.6/site-packages/setuptools/command/install_lib.py", line 17, in finalize_options
        self.set_undefined_options('install',('install_layout','install_layout'))
      File "/home/martin/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/distutils/cmd.py", line 290, in set_undefined_options
        setattr(self, dst_option, getattr(src_cmd_obj, src_option))
      File "/home/martin/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/distutils/cmd.py", line 103, in __getattr__
        raise AttributeError(attr)
    AttributeError: install_layout
    ----------------------------------------
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: /home/martin/.local/share/virtualenvs/nablaweb-2TimVObB/bin/python -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'/tmp/pip-install-042_z1b9/easy-thumbnails/setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'/tmp/pip-install-042_z1b9/easy-thumbnails/setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record /tmp/pip-record-8t5srbd7/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers /home/martin/.local/share/virtualenvs/nablaweb-2TimVObB/include/site/python3.6/easy-thumbnails Check the logs for full command output.
```

I have pipenv version version 2020.8.13, and have tried to install several different versions of python 3.6 (4, 12, 11) via pyenv, as well as via conda. The same error persists, while we are not able to reproduce the error on other systems. I am using Ubuntu

Comment: Just installed Ubuntu 20.04 (LTS), pyenv, and pipenv. Same issue here: I can neither install packages with `pip` nor with `pipenv`.

Comment: Also seeing this.  pipenv 2020.8.13 and python 3.6.9.  Different packages.  Similar error.

Answer (score 4):

I was struggling with moto dependency:

`pipenv run pip install --upgrade setuptools` fixed the issue.

then `pipenv install moto`

Answer (score 2):

try this

```
.venv/bin/pip3 install --upgrade setuptools
```

Answer (score 1):

Check if installing via `python -m pip <package_name>` or `python -m pipenv install` works.

Answer (score 0):

In my case none of the above solutions worked but this one did

```
pipenv run pip install --upgrade setuptools
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I must re-install `setuptools` to fix this issue:

`pip install --upgrade --force-reinstall setuptools`